# How can I get quantile label names in cut function?

Tags: r

I have this piece of code,

```
breaks=quantile(foo1$mnqtp, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.2))
```

Try 1

```
foo1$quantile <- with(foo1, cut(mnqtp, breaks=quantile(mnqtp, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.2)),
                            labels=c("0%","20%","40%","60%","80%"),
                            include.lowest=TRUE))
```

Try 2

```
foo1$quantile <- with(foo1, cut(mnqtp, breaks),labels=names(breaks),include.lowest=TRUE)
```

All I want is to rename the labels automatically to 90%, 100%, 20% etc based on the quantile. I can do it manually using Try 1, but I would like to have an automatic solution to this. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
foo1$quantile <- with(foo1, cut(mnqtp, breaks=qu <- quantile(mnqtp, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.2)),
                      labels=names(qu)[-1],
                      include.lowest=TRUE))
```

## Reproducible example

```
 iris$quantile <- with(iris, cut(Sepal.Width,
   breaks = qu <- quantile(Sepal.Width, probs = seq(0,1, by=0.2)),
   labels = names(qu)[-1], include.lowest=TRUE))
 head(iris$quantile)
 # [1] 100% 40%  80%  60%  100% 100%
 # Levels: 20% 40% 60% 80% 100%
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error in cut.default(mnqtp, breaks = qu <- quantile(mnqtp, probs = seq(0,  : 
  lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ

Comment: Try again, I had updated it. Note that nothing can have `0%` quantile so if you want that label you have to add it in manually.

Comment: Great. This works. But is it possible to list the range automatically as well? Like 90-92%, 92-94%. A bit tangential to my original question. I'll put a different question if required.

Comment: When I am doing this: foo1$range <-tapply(foo1$mnqtp, foo1$quantile, function(x) paste(range(x), collapse = ' - ')); I am getting this: error Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "range", value = c("0.195133307421781 - 0.264766548194162",  : 
  replacement has 5 rows, data has 104358

Comment: Yes. `v <- iris$Sepal.Width; d <- diff(range(v)); m <- min(v); iris$range <- factor(tapply(v, iris$quantile, function(x) paste(paste0( round((range(x)-m)/d, 2)*100, '%'), collapse = ' - '))); head(iris$range)`

Comment: See my second answer. @maximusyoda

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comments on my first answer, here is a formatted example with labels for the ranges:

```
quantiles <- function(x, probs = seq(0, 1, by = 0.2)) {
  cut(x, breaks = qu <- quantile(x, probs = probs),
    labels = names(qu)[-1], include.lowest = TRUE)
}

makeRange <- function(x) {
  d <- diff(range(x))
  m <- min(x)
  factor(tapply(x, quantiles(x),
    function(x) paste(paste0(round((range(x)-m)/d, 2)*100, '%'), collapse = ' - ')))
}

head(makeRange(iris$Sepal.Width))

 #        20%        40%        60%        80%       100%
 #   0% - 29%  33% - 42%  46% - 46%  50% - 58% 62% - 100%
 #   Levels: 0% - 29% 33% - 42% 46% - 46% 50% - 58% 62% - 100%
```